# Is this.props.children is different for <Route> than other React Components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Every react component is passed through the following function, found in node_modules ReactElement.js:

```
ReactElement.createElement = function (type, config, children){
   .
   .
   .
}
```

This also Includes `<Route>` and `<Router>`. Consider the following JSX Code from a [React Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZBxMljq9GSE) :

```
<Router history={hashHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={Layout}>
        <IndexRoute component={Featured} />
        <Route path="Settings" component={Settings} />
        <Route path="Archives" component={Archives} />
    </Route> 
</Router>
```

The above code will be transpiled into the code shown below using [Babel](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-0&code=%09%3CRouter%20history%3D%7BhashHistory%7D%3E%0A%09%09%3CRoute%20path%3D%22%2F%22%20component%3D%7BLayout%7D%3E%0A%09%09%09%3CIndexRoute%20component%3D%7BFeatured%7D%20%2F%3E%0A%09%09%09%3CRoute%20path%3D%22Settings%22%20component%3D%7BSettings%7D%20%2F%3E%0A%09%09%09%3CRoute%20path%3D%22Archives%22%20component%3D%7BArchives%7D%20%2F%3E%0A%09%09%3C%2FRoute%3E%20%0A%09%3C%2FRouter%3E):

```
"use strict";

React.createElement(
    Router,
    { history: hashHistory },
    React.createElement(
        Route,
        { path: "/", component: Layout },
        React.createElement(IndexRoute, { component: Featured }),
        React.createElement(Route, { path: "Settings", component: Settings }),
        React.createElement(Route, { path: "Archives", component: Archives })
    )
);
```

From this code, the "children" of the outer `<Route>` are the inner 3 `<Route>s`. We know that :

```
<MyContainer>
  <MyFirstComponent />
  <MySecondComponent />
</MyContainer>

class MyContainer extends React.Component{
   render(){
      return (
         .
         .
         //This will be MyFirstComponent or MySecondComponent 
         {this.props.children}
         .
         .
       );
   }
}
```

But the same is not true for the `<Route>s`. The value of `this.prop.children` for the JSX Router code applies to the `component` prop, but not the Router itself. Why is this behavior of this.props.children different for `<Route>` than any other ReactComponent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because Router deletes its Route children's children.

Here's the [`createRouteFromReactElement` function from `RouteUtils.js`](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v3.0.1/modules/RouteUtils.js#L15) in react-router 3.0.1:

```
export function createRouteFromReactElement(element) {
  const type = element.type
  const route = createRoute(type.defaultProps, element.props)

  if (route.children) {
    const childRoutes = createRoutesFromReactChildren(route.children, route)

    if (childRoutes.length)
      route.childRoutes = childRoutes

    delete route.children
  }

  return route
}
```

Notice the line fifth from the end: `delete route.children`.

Why does it do that? Consider this invariant warning [from `Route.prototype.render`](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v3.0.1/modules/Route.js#L34):

```
render() {
  invariant(
    false,
    '<Route> elements are for router configuration only and should not be rendered'
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining the "why". Before I accept this answer, could you please add the code in react where this.props.children is assigned to the component of the Route?

Comment: @AjayH It looks like that happens in the `render` method of [`RouterContext`](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v3.0.1/modules/RouterContext.js).